# MQTT as a variable on Bash?

Tags: bash, variable, mqtt

Hi I want to try and convert a message receieved from MQTT into a variable so I can do an "IF script" using messages sent from a certain topic on mqtt.

I tried this at top of script but didn't work:

```
Message = mosquitto_sub -d -t "test/test"
```

Thank you

Comment: The `mosquitto_sub` command runs indefinitely, right? Are you okay with using an option like `-C 5` to disconnect after receiving 5 messages?

Comment: I want it to run in background constantly. I want the script to play a sound if the message is the correct one or if something is received via that topic.

Answer (score 1):

Simply execute:

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t "#"  -C 1  > /var/spool/mosquitto/value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result of the command in a variable you've to write the line between cote character  like  this :

```
Message=`mosquitto_sub -d -t "test/test"`
```

If you want to use the variable in place of the command you should write the line like this :

```
Message="mosquitto_sub -d -t 'test/test'"
```

You've to look forward the special character in the bash script

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work with MQTT I might use node red in the end.